# Using tween.js in three.js to do rotation on x, y and z of a gltf

Tags: three.js, rotation, mesh, gltf, tween.js

I am having a difficult time to do a rotation on all axis in one statement. This is a loaded gltf that a mesh of it needs to do multiple rotations on x, y and z. My code using a single axis with .onUpdate works but I would like to have all three and possibly, just possibly eliminate .onUpdate in that. Here is what I am trying:

```
new TWEEN.Tween (theObject.rotation)
   .to ({x: theObject.rotation._x + degreeToRadian(-120),
         y: theObject.rotation._y + degreeToRadian(10),
         z: theObject.rotation._z + degreeToRadian(30)}, 3000)
   .delay (2000)
   .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
   .start ();
```

When I pass one axis argument in .to and then apply it in .onUpdate I get the rotation on that axis; and I would like to avoid writing 3 codes, one for each axis.

I have also tried Euler as the object structure is offering, but there was no luck:
`.to (new THREE.Euler(theObject.rotation._x + degreeToRadian(-120), theObject.rotation._y + degreeToRadian(10), theObject.rotation._z + degreeToRadian(30), "XYZ"), 3000)`
What am I missing in here?
Thank you

Comment: Why do these components have `_` prefix? `_x`, `_y`, `_z`

Comment: that is the structure. will not work without them either

Comment: any chance to provide a live working code snippet, that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I wish I could send you an image of the structure. if you want to see the move, here it is: https://codepen.io/mikebolt/pen/zzzvZg | you can then change position to rotation